Google Books API not delivering publisher
I have a google sheet weher column A holds ISBNs and I want to get further data like author, title, publisher, price.
For author and title it works quite well wenn I use the google books API and the code from here: https://github.com/usaussie/appscript-book-tracker/blob/main/Code.gs?ref=techupover.com
But the request doesn’t return the publisher.
Can someone help on how to retrieve this information?
Thank you and kind regards,
Luisa

The info is container in the results from the API. However, it's not being added to the sheet by the code. If you look at the code, you will see (L#164) that publisher is included in the results. You'll need to edit the code to include this property in your results.

I saw that but, but „publisher“ and also some other data is just not part of the returned object…

I'm going to try to reproduce your issue.

Publisher is returned as described in the script as volumeInfo.publisher.
